# Problema al insertar nuevo elemento en array

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola tengo el siguiente código:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function search(text) {
    var response = [];

    fs.readdir('documents',(err, files) => {
        files.forEach(file => {
            if(file.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) != -1){
                console.log("Encontrado " + file);
                response.push(file);
            }
        })
    });

    return response;
}

exports.search = search;
```

Lo que hace es buscar en una carpeta todos los archivos que contengan en su nombre(`file`) una cierta subcadena(`text`), la idea es que todos los archivos que coincidan deben almacenar su nombre en el array `response` el problema es que al retornar el array este me aparece vacío (me imprime `[]`)

Como pueden ver tengo un console.log para ver si es que en algún momento se encuentra un match y ya confirme que esto ocurre, ahora el problema es que pareciera que la linea del push jamas se ejecutara...

Comment: Eh intentado utilizar new Array() y no pasa nada nuevo

Comment: @Dev.Joel también eh hecho eso utilizó los [] por qué es la manera en que lo muestran aquí: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas haciendo una de funciones asíncronas, y, por lo tanto, cuando llegas a tu `return`, **no se ha ejecutado absolutamente ninguna línea de tu filtro**, por lo que devuelves un `array` vacío.

2 opciones:

#### 1. Utiliza *callbacks*

```
function search(text, callback ) {
  var response = [];

  fs.readdir('documents',(err, files) => {
    files.forEach( file => {
      if(file.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) != -1){
        console.log("Encontrado " + file);
        response.push(file);
      }
    } )
    callback( response );
  } );
}
```

#### 2. Usa funciones *síncronas*

```
function search(text) {
  var response = [ ],
      files = fs.readdirSync( 'documents' );

  files.forEach(file => {
    if(file.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) != -1){
      console.log("Encontrado " + file);
      response.push(file);
    }
  })

  return response;
}
```

Comment: Wow muchas gracias !

Comment: Se puede usar `filter` e `includes` para hacerlo más práctico: `const response = files.filter(file => file.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía gracias lo tomare en cuenta